# Two arrays in key and value in Dictionary swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have two Int arrays, for example:

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4] as Int

array2 = [10, 20, 30, 40] as Int

for work I need create Dictionary where Key - it's element from array1 and Value - it's element from array2, in my example - [1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40] as [Int:Int].

So, when I create loop:

```
    for i in 0..<arrayOfKeys.count {

        dictionaryOfData[arrayOfKeys[i]] = arrayOfValues[i]

    }
```

i see only last [4:40], but I know that I must have the Dictionary with 4 keys-values.

Give me, please, advise, how to do it in swift?!

**upd**, i find my problem - keys MUST be unique! So, thanks a lot for your answer and i knew about zip in swift

Comment: You can use `zip`.

Comment: The code you have would work fine, there has to be something else you are doing that's causing it to not work

Comment: looks like you're reinitializing your dictionary in for loop

Comment: so, after loop I use only print(dictionaryOfData) and see in console only last [4:40]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few solutions off the top of my head:

Init Arrays + Dict

```
let arrayOfValues = [1,2,3,4]
let arrayOfKeys = [1,2,3,4]

var arrayOfDict = [Int:Int]()
```

For loop solution:

```
for i in 0..<arrayOfKeys.count {
    if i < arrayOfValues.count {

            let key = arrayOfKeys[i]
            let value = arrayOfValues[i]

            arrayOfDict[key] = value
        }
    }
```

Using zip method solution:

```
for (key, value) in zip(arrayOfValues, arrayOfKeys) {
        arrayOfDict[key] = value
    }
```

From apple docs:

> zip: A sequence of pairs built out of two underlying sequences, where
>   the elements of the ith pair are the ith elements of each underlying
>   sequence.(iOS (9.0 and later))

Comment: thank you, but zip i can't use, because my app works in iOS 8.0+

Comment: and after loop solution i print arrayOfDict and see in console only last key-value - [4:4], i don't understand where is my mistake

Comment: I would suggest wrapping this up in a `convenience` initializer, in a class extension to `Dictionary`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]    
let array2 = [10, 20, 30, 40]

var dict = [Int: Int]()
zip(array1, array2).forEach { dict[$0] = $1 }

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use Zip you can enumerate your array if both arrays have the same number of elements:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let array2 = [10, 20, 30, 40]

var result: [Int:Int] = [:]

array1.enumerate().forEach{ result[$0.element] = array2[$0.index] }

result  // [2: 20, 3: 30, 1: 10, 4: 40]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated answer for Swift 4 taken from [www.tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_dictionaries.htm):

```
let cities = ["Delhi", "Bangalore", "Hyderabad"]
let distances = [2000, 10, 620]
let cityDistanceDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(cities, distances))
```